# Rails and Mailgun send CSV doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, csv, heroku, actionmailer

i'm want to generate CSV data and send it via mail to some email-address. For the generation of the CSV i'm using FasterCSV with the following code:

```
csv_data = FasterCSV.generate(:col_sep => ";") do |csv|
    csv << ["timestamp", "staff_firstname", "staff_lastname", "message"]

    log.each do |log_entry|
      csv << [log_entry.timestamp, log_entry.staff_firstname, log_entry.staff_lastname, log_entry.message]
    end

end
```

The csv_data i want to send via a ActionMailer method and therefore i'm using the following code:

```
def log_csv_export(log_csv, email)

   mail.attachments["log.csv"] = log_csv

   mail(:to => email, :subject => 'Export Log' )

end
```

To call the ActionMailer method i'm using:

```
AccountMailer.log_csv_export(csv_data, email).deliver
```

If I test it, the mail was send to the transmitted email address, but without an attachment. The csv-data is shown as plain text in the email, but not as attachment to save.

This problem only occurs if i send the mail via heroku mailgun. If i'm testing it with
 `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail` in the config, then it works.

Did someone knows what the issue is or what i need to change that it works?

Thank you.